# Advanced screen animation in Flutter (like Instagram story navigation pop)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How is it possible to make an animated transition of exactly this type?
I would like to focus on the "dynamism" that exists when scrolling down, the page follows the finger that scrolls and does not pop up to a certain threshold. at the same time it also tightens at the sides, if the scrolling threshold is not exceeded automatically an animation brings the page back up.

[image]

In the following link there is the video of the animation I'm talking about, (sorry but I couldn't compress it a lot to insert it here as an image)

[IG Pop Animation - Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mzNF.jpg)

Simplified question: how could one initially make the whole page respond to follow the finger scrolling down? With the following code I can pop the screen on the scroll down but I would like to add the animation.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.black,
body: GestureDetector(
  onLongPressStart: (details) => _onLongPressStart(details),
  onLongPressEnd: (details) => _onLongPressEnd(details),
  onTapUp: (details) => _onTapUp(details),
  onVerticalDragEnd: (details) => _onVerticalDragEnd(details),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[....],
  ),
),
);
}

void _onVerticalDragEnd(DragEndDetails dragEndDetails) {
  if (dragEndDetails.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.direction > 0) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use dismissible:

```
return Dismissible(
  direction: DismissDirection.down,
  onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.pop(context),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Container(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: too easy. not exactly the behavior I want. deepening should be a mix of Transform, GestureDetector and Hero animation (a formula should be added which simulates resistance once a certain threshold is exceeded)